# Selecting the correct clustering variable when calculating robust meta-analytic tests and error terms for dependent data

Tags: r, meta-analysis, nested-data

**Background**
I am revising a meta-analysis for publication and have been asked to adopt a multivariate modelling approach using the *rma.mv* and robust functions within the *metafor* package in *R*. Specifically, I have a sample of studies similar in structure to the below:

```
#TABLE OF STUDIES

StudyID   GroupID   DV          GroupType   EffectSize
-------------------------------------------------------
Study_1   Group_1   Outcome_A   Healthy     ES_1    
Study_1   Group_1   Outcome_B   Healthy     ES_2
Study_1   Group_1   Outcome_C   Healthy     ES_3
Study_1   Group_2   Outcome_A   Clinical    ES_4
Study_1   Group_2   Outcome_B   Clinical    ES_5
Study_1   Group_2   Outcome_C   Clinical    ES_6
Study_2   Group_3   Outcome_D   Healthy     ES_7
Study_2   Group_3   Outcome_D   Healthy     ES_8
Study_2   Group_4   Outcome_D   Clinical    ES_9
Study_2   Group_4   Outcome_D   Clinical    ES_10
Study_3   Group_5   Outcome_E   Healthy     ES_11
Study_3   Group_6   Outcome_E   Clinical    ES_12
```

In this example, StudyID = a unique identifier for each study; GroupID = a unique identifier for each sample of participants; DV = the dependent measure; and GroupType = the type of sample, for use in some moderator analyses. The effect sizes correspond to a particular finding from the cognitive literature. We would like to both estimate the aggregate effect within this literature, while also exploring heterogeneity and potential moderators (e.g., DV, GroupType). The issue is that we face various dependencies in the data. Our initial approach was to include only a single effect size for each study/group combination (picking the “best” outcome for each) and fit random effects models separately by group, combining those data only to fit a separate moderator analysis comparing across groups. A reviewer has now asked us to instead include all data together and to deal with these dependencies using the *robust* function.

**The Problem**

In applying this new approach, we are using *metafor* in *R* and have employed the following syntax:

```
meta_model <- rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ GroupType, random = ~ 1 | StudyID/GroupID, slab = authors, data=meta_data)

meta_model_robust <- robust.rma.mv(meta_model, cluster = meta_data$GroupID)
```

This syntax is inspired by the Kostantopoulos example here: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011. This includes random effects for both StudyID and GroupID. We were unsure whether we should also include an additional random effect corresponding to the individual effect sizes (e.g., EffectSizeID). More importantly, use of robust estimation procedures requires selection of a particular clustering variable, which could be either StudyID or GroupID in this case. Using StudyID recognizes dependencies arising from common study characteristics but ignores finer grained dependencies due to group features; GroupID recognizes dependencies arising from common participant characteristics but ignores broader dependencies due to study features. We are looking for a principled manner in which to decide whether we should be using StudyID or GroupID as our clustering variable.

**Questions**

With this in mind, we have two questions:

1. Which clustering variable (StudyID or GroupID) should be used when calculating the robust test statistics, etc.? Specifically, we would appreciate guidance as to whether there is a principled manner of making this decision, or if we should instead conduct both and report one as a sensitivity analysis. Intuitively, I would be inclined to use GroupID, since it is the random factor that codes for the highest degree of inter-independence of effects in this data set, that is, effect sizes coming from the same participants, and as such appears to me as a tighter control for non-independence of effect sizes.
2. Is it generally advisable to include a random effect for the individual effect sizes (e.g., as in a new variable, EffectSizeID) when using a multilevel modelling approach such as this? We have seen examples online both including or excluding such a random effect.

Comment: Try https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/